# Selenium retrieval of articles in a loop giving NoSuchElementException

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have a simple webpage containing a list of 100 articles which I want to scrape. When the page loads, a javascript runs in the background and retrieves the list of articles. 
The link of the webpage is: https://tools.wmflabs.org/topviews/?project=en.wikinews.org&platform=all-access&date=2016-01&excludes=Main_page

To retrieve the top 30 articles I have written this code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import numpy as np
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

class WikiNewsExtraction():

def __init__(self):

    self.all_articles_name = []
    self.all_articles_links = []
    self.initial_month = '2016-01'
    self.fixed_url = 'https://tools.wmflabs.org/topviews/?\
    project=en.wikinews.org&platform=all-access&date='
    self.exclude_page = '&excludes=Main_page'
    self.id_of_first_article_name = '//*[@id="topview-entry-1"]/td[2]/div'
    self.number_of_links_extracted = 30
    self.beginning_year = 2016
    self.end_year = 2018


def setup_selenium_driver(self):

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1024x1400")

    # download Chrome Webdriver  
    # https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/download
    # put driver executable file in the script directory
    chrome_driver_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "chromedriver")
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, 
    executable_path=chrome_driver_path)


def load_articles(self):


    self.all_articles_name.append('Article Name')
    self.all_articles_links.append('Article Link')

    for year in range(self.beginning_year,self.end_year+1):

        if year == self.end_year:
            end_month = datetime.today().month -1
        else:
            end_month = 12

        for month in range(1,end_month+1):

            if month<10:
                current_month = str(year)+'-0'+str(month)
            else:
                current_month = str(year)+'-'+str(month)

            url = self.fixed_url+current_month+self.exclude_page

            print('url = '+str(url))

            self.driver.get(url)
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(100)



            for index in range(self.number_of_links_extracted):

               xpath=self.id_of_first_article_name.replace('1',str(index+1))
               dom_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
                article_name = dom_element.text
                article_link = dom_element.get_attribute('href')
                self.all_articles_name.append(article_name)
                self.all_articles_links.append(article_link)


            print('Done '+str(month)+','+str(year)+'..')

    np.savetxt("Extracted_Data.csv", 
    np.column_stack((self.all_articles_name, self.all_articles_links)), 
    delimiter=",", fmt='%s')





extract = WikiNewsExtraction()
extract.setup_selenium_driver()
extract.load_articles()
```

On running it gives the error for xpath = //*[@id="topview-entry-3"]/td[2]/div
ie for 3rd entry of the table, or for some other numbered entry of the table. Whereas if the extraction is not done in loop, and if the article is directly extracted via the above xpath, it returns the correct data. I do not understand why this is happening. I have tried a longer waiting time in implicit_wait(), and I have tried driver.refresh(), but the problem still remains

Kindly help.

Comment: What are the _Manual Execution steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: I wanted to extract the top 30 most visited news articles on Wikinews from Jan 2016 to August 2018.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you observe carefully, while iterating in for loop and replacing index in below xpath, for 3 iteration, the for loop index will be 2 thereby it seems to replace, '2' in td[2] also which makes xpath obsolete.

```
self.id_of_first_article_name = '//*[@id="topview-entry-1"]/td[2]/div'
```

So, use this approach: give article number a unique name say: ART_ENTRY and the replace it in iterations as below:

```
self.id_of_first_article_name = '//*[@id="topview-entry-ART_ENTRY"]/td[2]/div'
```

**For loop:**

```
for index in range(self.number_of_links_extracted):
    xpath=self.id_of_first_article_name.replace('ART_ENTRY',str(index+1))
    dom_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

Sample code snippet which works fine:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get('https://tools.wmflabs.org/topviews/?project=en.wikinews.org&platform=all-access&date=2016-01&excludes=Main_page')
id_of_first_article_name ='//*[@id="topview-entry-ART_ENTRY"]/td[2]/div'
number_of_links_extracted = 30

for index in range(number_of_links_extracted):
    print((driver.find_element_by_xpath(id_of_first_article_name.replace('ART_ENTRY',str(index+1))).text).encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I have tried this as well, but it still doesn't work, it stops after extracting a variable number of articles on each page, sometimes 4 sometimes 3, whereas I am able to access the next article link (showing the exception) individually, outside the loop.

Comment: @JALAJGAMBHIR, I reviewed the [page](https://tools.wmflabs.org/topviews/?project=en.wikinews.org&platform=all-access&date=2016-01&excludes=Main_page) and see that the links are placed improperly. For example, the *topView-entry-95* in the DOM actually refers to the 94th article in UI. Check the screenshot [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-wlgZPBscJNrXtm8J5-OtlzzjbbsXBTj/view). This might have caused the issue

Comment: So, I placed the element accessing block inside a 'try-except' block, and now I am able to retrieve 27-28 articles out of the 30 intended. So that is kind of okayish for the task at hand. The problem seems to be the one you have pointed out. Thank you so much for taking the time!

Comment: @JALAJGAMBHIR, could you please accept the answer if it helped you.